# Button overlapping views on top of it

Tags: android

I made a custom view with a progress bar. To add it in all my fragments i made a base fragment. In the method `onActivityCreated` i added the following code:

```
activity?.run {
    loading = LoadingView(this)
    loading?.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    loading?.visibility = View.GONE
    (view as? ViewGroup)?.addView(loading)
}
```

And it works, but, when i make it visible, the buttons overlapped the progres bar in my `LoadingView`. So, when i show it i added `brintToFront()` method on a first test (that didnt work) and i saw i also had to use `invalidate`

```
protected fun showLoading() {
    loading?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    loading?.bringToFront()
    loading?.invalidate()
}
```

As this wasnt working either i started looking for a solution here and i found that the solution could be adding `translationZ` or `elevation` properties. So i tried to, but none is working.

The XML file of my view is:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: can you post your xml file ?

Comment: @Umair sure! in that constraint layout thats where i tried adding `elevation` and `translationZ`

Comment: Why don't you add the `LoadingView` into fragment xml instead of add it programmatically?

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen because, in this way i have it in all fragments

Comment: Can you add the xml of your `Activity` (which has the container of your `Fragment` and the `buttons` which overlap your loading view)?

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen it only contains a `FragmentContainerView`. Im using the navigation ui framework.

Comment: I've tried this and settings translationZ to 6f or more brings my view in front of buttons

Comment: @VitaliiMalyi LOL, adding it in code works perfectly. Adding it in XML fails. Please, add it as an answer and i will accept it

Comment: @cobolero I posted this as an answer, but the credit should go to you :) I just tried to reproduce the steps

Comment: @VitaliiMalyi thank you! :) now im just trying to understand whay i wrote wrong in the XML. As soon as i have it clear i will post it here too. Probably it was a small mistake that led to this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried this and settings `translationZ` to `6f` or more brings my view in front of buttons.
It seems that it should be set programmatically.

```
protected fun showLoading() {
    loading?.translationZ = 6f
    loading?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

Comment: I got it! The thing is that, as im adding the translation in a root element, when i add it into another view it gets reseted. If i include it into the XML it works fine.